# "Element locator with prefix '| id' is not supported" error in Robot framework

Tags: robotframework

I am using robot framework to test a GUI application ,
when  I try to run the test case , got an error like 
"Element locator with prefix '| id' is not supported " .
But I am using the latest version of selenium2library i.e.2.39.0 .

I will be thankful ,If somebody helps me out regarding the same .

and I have one more query ,i.e. how to click on the contents on GUI when working with robot framework

Thanks in advance

Comment: share your source code please, otherwise it is difficult to help you

Comment: Yes, please share your code. The error message hints that you have extra | character in there, but hard to know without seeing your code.

Comment: To click on a node in treeview , I have written a code like
"Click Element | id=treeview_tv_active " 
will this work ???

Comment: Or else could you please let me know the code to click on a node in treeview

Comment: Please share more of your code since now it is impossible to know how you have really formatter your code, and in this situation formatting matters a lot. "Treeview" and is not a standard element so we have no idea what you mean by that. "`Click Element | id=treeview_tv_active`" is valid, but the error message hints that you have double pipes or missing whitespace in there or something like that.

Answer (score 2):

I think the only way you can get such an error message is if you mix two styles of cell separators in your test. For example, you may be mixing tabs and pipes, or multiple spaces and pipes.

Robot determines which format to use on a line-by line basis. First, it looks for a tab anywhere in the line being parsed, and if it finds it, it uses tabs to split the line. If it doesn't find a tab, it checks to see if the line begins with a pipe and space. If so, it uses the pipe for a separator. Failing that, it uses multiple spaces as the separator.

I can reproduce the exact error you are getting by mixing pipes with either a tab or multiple spaces. For example, the following will generate the exact same error you report:

```
# the next line begins with two spaces
  click element  | id=treeview_tv_active
```

Robot will detect the two leading spaces and decide to use spaces to split the line into cells. Thus, the first cell will be `"click element"` and the second cell will be `"| id=treeview_tv_active"`. Selenium looks for everything before the "=" as the locator type, thus it's using `"| id"` as the locator, which is invalid and results in the error that you see.

Since you haven't shown us your code it's impossible to say for sure, but my guess is that the line causing the problem begins with a space or tab, or has a tab embedded somewhere else in the line, but later in the same line attempts to use pipes as cell separators.